# Blockchain syncing seems to be stuck bitcoin core wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core

I installed bitcoin core wallet  and it work for a month, now  syncing seems to be stuck on calculating progress increase per hour and nothing happens. how do I know if the syncing is progressing?